# Word for a multi-level stairway

Tags: terminology

A stairway made of flights where each flight leads to a small landing from which the next flight travels in the opposite direction to the first flight.

So, for example, I take a flight down by going north, arrive at the landing, take a few steps to the left - say - turn about, and take the next flight down by going south.

What kind of stairway is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Homesthetics.net](https://homesthetics.net/architecture-stairs/), the type of stairs you are looking for are called "half landing staircases":

> Next up is the Half Landing Staircase. You must already be familiar with this type of stairs. These are most commonly found in apartment and tall office buildings.
>
> In the previous case *[straight staircase with intermediate landing]*, the landing flowed along with the staircase. However, in this case, the landing changes the direction of the flight of stairs by 180 degrees. It is almost like taking a U-turn, albeit in the upward direction.

The [Architecture Exposition website](http://www.archiexpo.com/architecture-design-manufacturer/staircase-commercial-buildings-36040.html) also refers to that style as a "Half-turn staircase".

[Other](https://www.architecturaldigest.com/story/types-of-stairs-explained) [sites](http://weldwide.com/help-guides/staircase-terminology/) mention both "half-turn" and "U-shaped" as possibilities.

Comment: Another term for it is a 'dog-leg staircase' (because it has a bend in it).